# How do you get maven child projects to build in Jenkins when using CI Friendly versions?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am using CI Friendly versioning in my Parent-Child Maven project. I can't get the child to build on the Jenkins server. It builds fine on my server. I am getting the "Failed to parse POMs" error saying it can't find "myProj-parent:pom:${revision}" in nexus. I am using the Maven Flatten Plugin and as I said it works when I run Maven from my server. But for some reason in Jenkins it is not resolving.

The "revision" is set in the properties section of the parent POM.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem when we do a sparse checkout of the child module only.
We solved it by adding a sparse checkout of all pom.xml files.
I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Jenkins maven-plugin, the failure may be due to an [old unresolved bug](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-23846).  A workaround from the JIRA conversation is to use the [pipeline-maven-plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-maven/) (withMaven step).

The pipeline-maven-plugin exposes a similar [bug in Maven](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6727) that was fixed in version 3.8.5.  My build works using the pipeline-maven-plugin after upgrading Maven on the Jenkins server.