# Maven friendly CI - revision property doesn't work with Jenkins build

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3

I'm trying to use [maven friendly ci](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) for my multi-module project. My project has three levels of parent child hierarchy, i.e., my parent project has few child projects and those child projects has many other child projects within them.

I have added a sample of my pom files below. My parent pom has a flatten plugin as well, everything works fine in my local machine. But when I build it from Jenkins, it doesn't work. And I get the below error

Error

> [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the
> POMs: [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for
> com.faskan:child-module:[unknown-version]:
> Could not transfer artifact
> com.faskan:parent-module:pom:${revision} from/to nexus

Parent project's pom.xml

```
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.faskan</groupId>
        <artifactId>global-parent-dependency</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>org.faskan</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>project parent pom</name>

    <properties>
        <revision>21.15.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>

   <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <configuration>                
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <!-- enable flattening -->
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>flatten</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <!-- ensure proper cleanup -->
                <execution>
                    <id>flatten.clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

...
</project>
```

Child project's pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>child-module</artifactId>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.faskan</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>

    <name>child admin</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
..
</project>
```

Child of child project (grand child)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>grand-child-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>child of child module</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.faskan</groupId>
        <artifactId>child-module</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
..
</project>
```

I found a similar question [How do you get maven child projects to build in Jenkins when using CI Friendly versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58608128/how-do-you-get-maven-child-projects-to-build-in-jenkins-when-using-ci-friendly-v). Not sure if mine is the same because I don't get any parse failure errors.

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration is missing in your parent pom.xml for the flatten plugin:

```
<configuration>
  <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
  <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
</configuration>
```

I believe you have to add this configuration for ci-friendly projects, as explained [here](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#install-deploy).

Answer (score -1):

In

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.faskan</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
    </parent>
```

you can't have `${revision}` for `version`. Maven don't know where to get it. You need to use actual version.

PS: I don't know how you manage to build it locally.

Comment: I actually think you can: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#multi-module-setup

Comment: I was referring to the documentation https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#multi-module-setup. The sample in the documentation uses ${revision} for version as well. And in my local it was failing initially and when I added the flatten maven plugin it started working locally.

Comment: The given answer is not correct because that's the intended thing to get rid of that hard coded version... But the most important part is the usage of the flatten maven plugin .... otherwise it will fail (You have to read the docs until the end of the page).